# How to fetch data to select option in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

Scenerio :

1. I have a list of status (i.e:Pending, Review, Approve + ... ) stored in database table (i.e Statuses)
2. I have create order form  where I need to select those (status in form while creating order)
   Now tell me how can I fetch those data to the create.blade & should i have to write relation in Model or not? Please help!
   I have seen few articles but they don't mention about Models and Controller part so I was super confused. I need some neat and clean way to achieve without laravel collective. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In YourController.php

```
public function create(){
$status = Status::all(); //fetch from Status Model
return view('your.blade.php',compact('status'));
}
```

in your.blade.php

```
<select >
<option value=""></option>
@foreach($status as $stat) //Loop and Populate your data
<option value="{{$stat.id}}">{{$stat.name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

if I understood your question well. you can pass your data like that

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to pull that Status model in my controller also. ANd it worked fine.

Comment: does it work fine or it needs more clarification